# Command Line - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, terminal, try-catch, command-line-arguments, filenotfoundexception

I am working on creating a tester.

When I tried

javac WordListsTester.java
java WordListsTester a.txt

I think it should show an error message as the file has to be "dictionary.txt" but, it does not.

What should I fix?

```
public class WordListsTester {
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    WordLists scrabble = new WordLists("dictionary.txt");

    String[] containLetter = scrabble.containsLetter(3, 'a');
    output(containLetter, "containsLetter.txt");

    String[] wordsStarts = scrabble.startsWith(3, 'a');
    output(wordsStarts, "startsWith.txt");

    String[] wordLength = scrabble.lengthN(3);
    output(wordLength, "lengthN.txt");

    String[] multiLetter = scrabble.multiLetter(2, 'h');
    output(multiLetter, "multiLetter.txt");

    String[] vowelHeavy = scrabble.vowelHeavy(5, 2);
    output(vowelHeavy, "vowelHeavy.txt");

    input.close();

}

public static void output(String[] words, String fileName) {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        if (words.length == 0) {
            System.out.println("NO matched Words exist");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            out.println(words[i]);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Invalid file name.");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you mean by *the file has to be "dictionary.txt"*? You're passing `a.txt` as argument to your program, but your program doesn't do anything with arguments.

Comment: I mean, as I have to read dictionary.txt, I want to see an error when I pass a.txt which is not correct.

Comment: Then check that args[0] is equal to "dictionary.txt". But what's the point of passing an argument in the first place, if its only valid value is "dictionary.txt"? That's a bit like "you're allowed to choose the color of your car, but only if you choose black".

Comment: You mean you want `if (args.length > 0 && !args[0].equals("dictionary.txt"))  System.out.println("You typed " + args[0] + " instead of 'dictionary.txt'");`?

Comment: Isnt it args[0] if I enter java WordListsTester.java a.txt ? What do you mena for args[0] here?

Comment: args[0] is the first argument passed to the program. Since you passed a.txt as argument, args[0] contains "a.txt".

Comment: Yes, since I have written "filenotfoundexception" I want to see an error for it as there is no file on the folder except for dictionary.txt

Comment: So, you want to open the file passed as argument, instead of systematically opening the file dictionary.txt, right? Then pass args[0] instead of "dictionary.txt" to the method opening the file (which you didn't post).

Answer (score 0):

```
WordLists scrabble = new WordLists(args[0]);
```

Not sure what this program does exactly.

Not sure if file name is being checked inside the WordLists class.

But if you want to check USER INPUT, you need to check args[0].